# Unable to expose QtQuick2 object to embeded html in Qt android 5.7

Tags: android, qt, qtquick2

Could some one explain me how to expose QtQuick object to Html. I have used sample code from google but it's giving following errors.

**Invalid property name 'experimental'**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtWebChannel 1.0
import QtWebKit 3.0
import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0

QtObject {
    id: myObject

    WebChannel.id: "foo"
    signal someSignal(string message);
    function someMethod(message) {
        console.log(message);
        someSignal(message);
        return "foobar";
    }
    property string hello: "world"
}
WebView {
    experimental.webChannel.registeredObjects: [myObject]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included 'qwebchannel.js' in your html code? According to the doc, you should include this js library in your html file.

Comment: thats fine but from QML side i have issues i dont have experimental mudule in qt andriod 5.7